# how can I create the negation of mathcal letters

Tags: math-operators

I know that the negation of < is got by `\not <`. The same with many symbols. But this doesn't work with mathcal letters for example, like  `\not \mathcal{R}` or `\mathcal{\not R}`.

Comment: Why would you want such a thing?

Comment: @Vishal essentially I want to negate relation symbols

Comment: For that you probably need the $\notin \mathcal{R}$ command rather than $\in$  negation of $\mathcal{R}$

Comment: @Vishal Well, yes but $\notin$ is for the negation of the inclusion symbol. I need to negate any other symbol, specifically mathcal letters.

Comment: That's some weird math, man (or woman, as luck would have it). XD  Is there any real example we can look (rather stare blankly) at?

Comment: @SeanAllred It's not weird math, we always have relation symbols: =, <, >, +,-,etc. but when we are dealing with them in general, I mean no particular symbol is used, like when we study logic or set theory then we use letters instead.

Comment: Hmmm - I can see that.  I suppose I never got far enough into it where `$~$` and friends didn't suffice.

Answer (score 28):

The package `cancel` can draw a diagonal line.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{cancel}
\begin{document}

$\cancel{\mathcal{R}}$

\end{document}
```

> [image]

Answer (score 23):

`\not` is designed for negating relation symbols basically as wide as the equals sign. But it doesn't always work and, for instance, one should use `\notin` rather than `\not\in` because the membership sign is too high.

Here's a possible solution for your “negated relations”:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\calrel}{sm}
 {%
  \mathrel{
   \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {\notcalrel{#2}}
   {\mathcal{#2}}%
  }%
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\notcalrel}{m}
 {%
  \ooalign{$\mathcal{#1}$\cr\noalign{\kern-.2ex}\hidewidth$/$\hidewidth\cr}
 }

\begin{document}
We have $x \calrel{R} y$ but $a \calrel*{R} b$.

We have $x \calrel*{R} y$ but $a \calrel{R} b$.

\end{document}
```

With `\calrel{R}` you get a relation symbol with the correct spacing around it; the *-variant adds the negation bar.

Note that the *-variant will not work in subscripts or superscripts; this shouldn't be much of a concern, though.

[image]

Using this with `\mathcal{T}` poses some problems: the slope of the glyph is very similar to the slope of the slash and the central bar gets in the way. A solution might be to rotate a bit the slash, making it longer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,graphicx}
\NewDocumentCommand{\calrel}{sm}
 {%
  \mathrel{
   \IfBooleanTF{#1}
   {\notcalrel{#2}}
   {\mathcal{#2}}%
  }%
 }
\newcommand{\notcalrel}[1]
 {%
  \ooalign{%
   $\mathcal{#1}$\cr
   \noalign{\kern-.05ex}
   \hidewidth\kern.05em\rotatedslash\hidewidth\cr}
 }
\newcommand\rotatedslash{%
  \rotatebox[origin=c]{-20}{\scalebox{1}[1.2]{/}}%
}

\begin{document}
We have $x \calrel{R} y$ but $a \calrel*{R} b$.

We have $x \calrel*{R} y$ but $a \calrel{R} b$.

We have $x \calrel{S} y$ but $a \calrel*{S} b$.

We have $x \calrel*{S} y$ but $a \calrel{S} b$.

We have $x \calrel{T} y$ but $a \calrel*{T} b$.

We have $x \calrel*{T} y$ but $a \calrel{T} b$.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The first one looks really nice. It's probably worth just not using T.